# Django - int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Patients'

Tags: python, django

for the context :

- I have 2 tables, user (which is a copy of the auth_user table, with small modifications) and patients
- I want to make a DetailView without passing the pk argument, so my user don't have access to his id
- The primary key of Patients is a the foreign key "patients" in User, so I can link these two tables

My Patients model:

```
class Patients(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    # And other keys not importants
```

My views.py:

```
class ProfilView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    login_url = '/membres/login/'
    #model = Patients
    template_name = 'membres/profil.html'
    def get_object(self):
        user_loggin = get_object_or_404(User, pk=self.request.user.id)
        return Patients.objects.get(pk=user_loggin.patients)
```

I think I return something wrong, but after searching on internet a lot, I don't understand how i'm suppose to make this working, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying on the `pk` requires a integer object not a `Patients` object.

You should specify the `id` of the related `patients` object:

```
Patients.objects.get(pk=user_loggin.patients.id)
#                                           ^^^
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `patients.pk`?

Comment: @Sagar The `id` is also the primary key

Comment: Thank you, it work perfectly !! (i'm new to django, it's quite difficult at the beginning)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye - You say "`id` is also the primary key" but that is not the case if you manually set a primary key. `id` is the name of the field django automatically creates if you do not specify your own. `pk` always exists and is used to access the primary key value, irrespective of the field name.

Comment: @Tony I meant in this context